# GitHub Pages Jekyll theme working for pages but not for posts

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I have a Jekyll-based GitHub Pages blog using a slightly modified Hyde theme. It has four pages using the 'page' layout that can be accessed using the permanent sidebar: Blog, About, Projects, and Publications. Here is what these pages look like:

[image: Imgur]

The Blog and Project pages have sub-pages that use 'post' and 'project' layouts, respectively. They were working fine for several months without a problem, but yesterday after making a new post, I found that the theme is no longer working for my posts or projects, even though it continues to work for my pages. This is what my posts look like:

[image: Imgur]

All the content is there for the sidebar and post, and the Markdown is rendered, but the Jekyll theme doesn't seem to be working. My project pages look similar.

I am very confused because I had not changed anything related to the theme or layouts in about two months, and I know my site was working normally even a few days ago. This problem seemed to come out of nowhere and I have had no luck finding a solution.

Here is the repository for the site: https://github.com/rgriff23/rgriff23.github.io

Comment: The problem is that the `{{ site.baseurl }}` is not working properly since it is not prepending to the css path so the CSS files are not loaded.

Comment: Its weird that i tested you code locally it's fine. Try replacing the `{{ site.baseurl }}` with `/` in `home.html` and check.

Comment: Alright, replacing `{{ site.baseurl }}` with `/` in `head.html` fixed my problem! I'm rather disturbed by this, any idea why this would suddenly become a problem?

Comment: PS feel free to write as an answer if you want me to accept it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the `{{ site.baseurl }}` is not working properly since it is not prepending to the css path so the CSS files are not loaded.

Try replacing the `{{ site.baseurl }}` with `/` in `head.html` which should fix the issue for sure.

Also check [this post](https://byparker.com/blog/2014/clearing-up-confusion-around-baseurl/) which explains the `baseurl`

Comment: I still don't understand why {{ site.baseurl }} would stop working after it had been working in the past. I'm glad my site is working now, but still want to understand why it broke. If anyone has any idea...